# which is better "for(int i = 0; i != 5; ++i)" or "for(int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)"?

Tags: c++, c, performance, for-loop

which is better `for(int i = 0; i != 5; ++i)` or `for(int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)`?

Please explain the rationale, if possible.

I read somewhere that != operator is better than comparison operators. also pre-increment operator is better than post-increment operator, since it doesn't require any temporary variable to store the intermediate value.

Is there any better form of for loop than these two?

p.s: I use the former one as suggested by one of the sources, which i don't remember now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are at least two differences:

- the first one will iterate 5 times (from 0 to 4), while the second one will iterate 6 times (from 0 to 5).

  This is a logic difference, and it depends on what you need to do.

  If what you meant for the second example was `i<=4` (versus `i!=5`) you shouldn't bother: any compiler will always be able to optimize such a trivial expression even with optimizations turned off.
- the second difference is the use of operator `++`: in a case you use the prefix version, while in the other the postfix version.

  This doesn't make difference for native types, but could do some difference with user defined types (ie classes, structs, enums, ...), since the user could overload the operator, and the postfix one (`var ++`) could be a little slower sometimes.

Comment: also, there is no safety on the first one; if for some reason i goes beyond 5, you have an infinite loop.

Comment: @MiRAGe: if something like that happens it would mean your program is not behaving in a predictable way, and I think that **in general** there'd be no point in ensuring that such loop doesn't go to infinity...

Comment: peoro: that depends... if you're doing something like for (double d = 0; d != x; d += y) you may not care if there's some epsilon disparity that prevents d from ever quite equaling x, even though mathematically it eventually should: in that scenario `<` is indeed safer.

Comment: @Tony: iterating on a floating point value is a different case. Yet another different case is when you're iterating on an STL-like iterator: in that case you're forced to use `!=`.

Comment: @MiRAGe: if incrementing the **integer** 4 by 1 does not give you 5, the style of a `for` statement is the least of your problems.

Comment: @JeremyP, in the case I mentioned you might not be the best coder, but the kind of for-loop definitely matters here :) You can bash my theory any way you want; it does happen. Bad coders still exist, and they always will. Therefore you should always keep these kinds of scenarios in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Using "i < 5" would be the form most people would expect to see on a for loop based on common usage. There is nothing wrong of course with "i != 5" or "i <= 5" (expect they'll give different loop counts) but if I see either of those forms I have to stop and think because it's not the most common form.

So I would always write "i < 5" unless there was a strong reason to do otherwise

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you should write for PEOPLE not the computer.

The "for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)" form makes it very clear that the valid range is "0 through 4" and nothing else.

And as other people said, this form make sure that funny code in the loop is much less likely to cause an infinite loop. And as other people have said, use the form that reflects what you mean.

Note that "less than" is the idiom commonly used in c (which means more programmers will expect that). That's another reason to prefer the "for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)" form.

Answer (score 1):

My teacher in the C++ language told me to use the canonical forms: `for(int x=0; x != 5; ++i)`

Thou the other works just fine but suppose you want to use the loop on a iterator. Then <= does not has to be properly defined and a postfix inc might make your program spend alot of time copying objects.

So he made us use the forms

`for(int i=begin; x != end; ++i)` and `for(int i=begin; end != i--; )`

Comment: x is of type int, so there's no difference for using ++ before or after variable

Comment: But, what references support the notion that != is the canonical form? I definitely haven't observed that in my years of C++ programming. See JohnB's answer for an example of someone who feels `<` is the canonical form.  I'm not weighing in on either side, but some references would be useful.

Comment: yes there is, i++ is a right hand variable. so no value can be asigned to it. ++i is a left hand variable.

Comment: @Tony. I can't find it any where on his work on the net. But this is the book he wrote for it: http://www.icce.rug.nl/documents/cplusplus/. But he uses other forms there as well. (Which is a bit typical) But he did made a point that a iterator might over write the != operator but not the < operator.

Comment: This is exactly my beef with teachers. I was a teacher. Teachers say whatever they want, and students take it as "Well this is what I was taught...". What you were taught is just their opinion, informed or not.

Answer (score 1):

which is better for(int i = 0; i != 5; ++i) or for(int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)?

the 2nd one since its a Bolian Operator, then this for(int i = *_* ; i <= __ or etc ; i++ increment )? --> it's widely used as now a days even when are beginners  in programming.

Answer (score 0):

You should use whichever of `<`, `<=`, `!=` etc. best expresses your application logic, but if there's no reason to prefer any particular style, then be consistent.  In informing that decision, the `<` and `!=` operators have the advantage of allowing comparisons between 0-based indices and `sizeof` or STL-style `size` / `length` values, as in:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < my_vector.size(); ++i)
    ...
```

The `<` and `<=` operators sometimes guard against incrementing past the terminating value (if you've got another condition inside the loop under which you increment/add-to `i`, or there's some floating point rounding/representation disparity).  Not often actually significant, but saving an occasional bug is better than nothing.

Given '<' is the intersection of these two sets, it's a popular choice.  To my mind, `<` also communicates the states under which the loop runs... a more positive assertion rather than the `!=` style.  In general, negative assertions are discouraged in programming (e.g. `bool invalid` is more complicated to get your head around reliably than `bool valid`, especially in complex boolean expression and when double-negatives are introduced).

This is of course for numeric types.  Other types may imply other styles... for example, use of `!= sentinel`.  I prefer to have the choice of operator help document these usage implications of the type, though that's a personal choice and arguably redundant.

Otherwise, preincrement can be more efficient for complicated types than post- as it avoids a temporary.

Answer (score 0):

The condition != is simply faster than both < and (even more) <= otherwise it is just question of taste, though one needs to be careful of possible infinite loops.